# Creating an alarm system: make sure member has a certain role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot for my friend's server and he wants me to create an alarm system. I cannot get this member in an if statement to actually work

My code:

```py
@commands.command(aliases=['an'])
async def attacknorth(self, ctx, member:discord.Member):
    guild = ctx.guild
    alarmRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Alarm Owner")

    if member == alarmRole:
        await ctx.send("North kingdom has alarm role")
    else:
        await ctx.send("They dont have alarm role")
```

Comment: I assume members _have_ roles, but you're checking if member is _equal_ to a role...

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables. it is called `"print debuging"`. Maybe you compare wrong values.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John Gordon had mentioned in the comments, you are checking if the member is equal to a role, rather than if the member has the role. You can use the [`discord.Member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.Member.roles) attribute, which is a `list`, and check if the Alarm Owner role is **in** this list. Please view the revised code below.

```py
@commands.command(aliases=['an'])
async def attacknorth(self, ctx, member:discord.Member):
    guild = ctx.guild
    alarmRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Alarm Owner")

    if alarmRole in member.roles:
        await ctx.send("North kingdom has alarm role")
    else:
        await ctx.send("They don't have alarm role")
```

[image: Command working as expected]

**Helpful Links**:

- [how do I check if a user has a specific role in discord](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70055064/14420546) (newest answer) - SO
- [check if a user has a particular role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57664884/discord-py-check-if-a-user-has-a-particular-role) - SO

Comment: Thanks really appreciate it, worked wonders on me!

Comment: @Wep if this answer has helped you, do accept this as the answer to your question by pressing the tick button beneath this answer's upvote and downvote 